# Global navigation does not show folders in subsites

Tags: 2013, navigation, global-navigation

In a SharePoint 2013 publishing site, I set up global navigation to show structural navigation.

Basically, I have this following site hierarchy:

- root

  - subsite

    - sub-subsite
    - sub-subsite2
  - subsite2

This is the physical structure, but I want to set up this *logical* user navigation:

- root

  - subsite

    - sub-subsite
    - ***Folder***

      - sub-subsite2
  - ***Folder***

    - subsite2

To achieve this result, I tweak the navigation of both *subsite* and *root* to create a navigation folder.

However, this is not working as expected. The ***folder*** in the root site is shown in the navigation, but the ***folder*** within the subsite does not appears.

## **How can I set up my navigation to reach my goal ?**

Actually, the application I'm working on uses a custom master page. If I have to update it, it can be done.

By now, the navigation menu is defined using:

```
<PortalSiteMapDataSource
    ID="topSiteMap"
    runat="server"
    EnableViewState="false"
    SiteMapProvider="GlobalNavigationSwitchableProvider"
    StartFromCurrentNode="true"
    StartingNodeOffset="0"
    ShowStartingNode="false"
    TrimNonCurrentTypes="Heading" />
<AspMenu
    ID="TopNavigationMenu"
    runat="server"
    EnableViewState="false"
    DataSourceID="topSiteMap"
    AccessKey="&lt;%$Resources:wss,navigation_accesskey%&gt;"
    UseSimpleRendering="true"
    UseSeparateCSS="false"
    Orientation="Horizontal"
    StaticDisplayLevels="1"
    AdjustForShowStartingNode="false"
    MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels="2"
    SkipLinkText=""></AspMenu>
```

FYI, here is the actual result:

[image: subsite]

[image: subsite 2]

And here is the navigation settings of the root site:

[image: root nav settings]

Finally, the navigation settings of the subsite:

[image: subsite nav]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the solution was quite simple. I had to remove the attribute `TrimNonCurrentTypes` from my datasource:

```
<PortalSiteMapDataSource
    ID="topSiteMap"
    runat="server"
    EnableViewState="false"
    SiteMapProvider="GlobalNavigationSwitchableProvider"
    StartFromCurrentNode="true"
    StartingNodeOffset="0"
    ShowStartingNode="false"
    />
```

And it solved the issue.

Don't know why this attribute is set by default on OOB master pages.